Dump all key pair of a json with JQ
Today I have big troubles in parsing huge json files (bigger than a megabyte) with only pure bash functions (performance issues), so I would like to use JQ parser https://jqlang.github.io/jq/ to speed up json parsing.
I'm using some bash functions which help parsing JSON and those functions are highly used in scripts so it will not be possible to change them everywhere but I can upgrade their contents in the library used by all scripts with jq parsing as soon as it produce the exact same output.
But for the moment I did not succeeded in producing the same output with some jq filters / functions.
Lets see an example, here is a very simple json sample :
{"success":true,"result":[{"duplex":"full","mac_list":[{"mac":"00:00:00:2F:8E:AB","hostname":"firewall-net90d"}],"name":"Ethernet 1","link":"up","id":1,"mode":"1000BaseT-FD","speed":"1000","rrd_id":"1"},{"duplex":"half","name":"Ethernet 2","link":"down","id":2,"mode":"10BaseT-HD","speed":"10","rrd_id":"2"},{"duplex":"half","name":"Ethernet 3","link":"down","id":3,"mode":"10BaseT-HD","speed":"10","rrd_id":"3"},{"duplex":"half","name":"Ethernet 4","link":"down","id":4,"mode":"10BaseT-HD","speed":"10","rrd_id":"4"},{"duplex":"full","name":"NBAplug","link":"up","id":5,"mode":"1000BaseT-FD","speed":"1000","rrd_id":"nbaplug"},{"duplex":"auto","mac_list":[{"mac":"00:00:00:43:B3:73","hostname":"00:00:00:43:B3:73"},{"mac":"00:00:00:1A:66:60","hostname":"00:00:00:1A:66:60"},{"mac":"00:00:00:09:00:13","hostname":"00:00:00:09:00:13"},{"mac":"00:00:00:80:29:7C","hostname":"abcd-PLAYER"},{"mac":"00:00:00:09:00:12","hostname":"firewall-net101f-cluster"},{"mac":"00:00:00:A0:EF:82","hostname":"00:00:00:A0:EF:82"}],"name":"Sfp lan","link":"up","id":9999,"mode":"10000-FD","speed":"10000","rrd_id":"sfp_lan"}]}

Processing this JSON with the BASH function produce this output :
success = true
result[0].duplex = full
result[0].mac_list[0].mac = 00:00:00:2F:8E:AB
result[0].mac_list[0].hostname = firewall-net90d
result[0].mac_list[0] = {"mac":00:00:00:2F:8E:AB,"hostname":firewall-net90d}
result[0].mac_list = [{"mac":00:00:00:2F:8E:AB,"hostname":firewall-net90d}]
result[0].name = Ethernet 1
result[0].link = up
result[0].id = 1
result[0].mode = 1000BaseT-FD
result[0].speed = 1000
result[0].rrd_id = 1
result[0] = {"duplex":full,"mac_list":[{"mac":00:00:00:2F:8E:AB,"hostname":firewall-net90d}],"name":Ethernet 1,"link":up,"id":1,"mode":1000BaseT-FD,"speed":1000,"rrd_id":1}
result[1].duplex = half
result[1].name = Ethernet 2
result[1].link = down
result[1].id = 2
result[1].mode = 10BaseT-HD
result[1].speed = 10
result[1].rrd_id = 2
result[1] = {"duplex":half,"name":Ethernet 2,"link":down,"id":2,"mode":10BaseT-HD,"speed":10,"rrd_id":2}
result[2].duplex = half
result[2].name = Ethernet 3
result[2].link = down
result[2].id = 3
result[2].mode = 10BaseT-HD
result[2].speed = 10
result[2].rrd_id = 3
result[2] = {"duplex":half,"name":Ethernet 3,"link":down,"id":3,"mode":10BaseT-HD,"speed":10,"rrd_id":3}
result[3].duplex = half
result[3].name = Ethernet 4
result[3].link = down
result[3].id = 4
result[3].mode = 10BaseT-HD
result[3].speed = 10
result[3].rrd_id = 4
result[3] = {"duplex":half,"name":Ethernet 4,"link":down,"id":4,"mode":10BaseT-HD,"speed":10,"rrd_id":4}
result[4].duplex = full
result[4].name = NBAplug
result[4].link = up
result[4].id = 5
result[4].mode = 1000BaseT-FD
result[4].speed = 1000
result[4].rrd_id = nbaplug
result[4] = {"duplex":full,"name":NBAplug,"link":up,"id":5,"mode":1000BaseT-FD,"speed":1000,"rrd_id":nbaplug}
result[5].duplex = auto
result[5].mac_list[0].mac = 00:00:00:43:B3:73
result[5].mac_list[0].hostname = 00:00:00:43:B3:73
result[5].mac_list[0] = {"mac":00:00:00:43:B3:73,"hostname":00:00:00:43:B3:73}
result[5].mac_list[1].mac = 00:00:00:1A:66:60
result[5].mac_list[1].hostname = 00:00:00:1A:66:60
result[5].mac_list[1] = {"mac":00:00:00:1A:66:60,"hostname":00:00:00:1A:66:60}
result[5].mac_list[2].mac = 00:00:00:09:00:13
result[5].mac_list[2].hostname = 00:00:00:09:00:13
result[5].mac_list[2] = {"mac":00:00:00:09:00:13,"hostname":00:00:00:09:00:13}
result[5].mac_list[3].mac = 00:00:00:80:29:7C
result[5].mac_list[3].hostname = abcd-PLAYER
result[5].mac_list[3] = {"mac":00:00:00:80:29:7C,"hostname":abcd-PLAYER}
result[5].mac_list[4].mac = 00:00:00:09:00:12
result[5].mac_list[4].hostname = firewall-net101f-cluster
result[5].mac_list[4] = {"mac":00:00:00:09:00:12,"hostname":firewall-net101f-cluster}
result[5].mac_list[5].mac = 00:00:00:A0:EF:82
result[5].mac_list[5].hostname = 00:00:00:A0:EF:82
result[5].mac_list[5] = {"mac":00:00:00:A0:EF:82,"hostname":00:00:00:A0:EF:82}
result[5].mac_list = [{"mac":00:00:00:43:B3:73,"hostname":00:00:00:43:B3:73},{"mac":00:00:00:1A:66:60,"hostname":00:00:00:1A:66:60},{"mac":00:00:00:09:00:13,"hostname":00:00:00:09:00:13},{"mac":00:00:00:80:29:7C,"hostname":abcd-PLAYER},{"mac":00:00:00:09:00:12,"hostname":firewall-net101f-cluster},{"mac":00:00:00:A0:EF:82,"hostname":00:00:00:A0:EF:82}]
result[5].name = Sfp lan
result[5].link = up
result[5].id = 9999
result[5].mode = 10000-FD
result[5].speed = 10000
result[5].rrd_id = sfp_lan
result[5] = {"duplex":auto,"mac_list":[{"mac":00:00:00:43:B3:73,"hostname":00:00:00:43:B3:73},{"mac":00:00:00:1A:66:60,"hostname":00:00:00:1A:66:60},{"mac":00:00:00:09:00:13,"hostname":00:00:00:09:00:13},{"mac":00:00:00:80:29:7C,"hostname":abcd-PLAYER},{"mac":00:00:00:09:00:12,"hostname":firewall-net101f-cluster},{"mac":00:00:00:A0:EF:82,"hostname":00:00:00:A0:EF:82}],"name":Sfp lan,"link":up,"id":9999,"mode":10000-FD,"speed":10000,"rrd_id":sfp_lan}
result = [{"duplex":full,"mac_list":[{"mac":00:00:00:2F:8E:AB,"hostname":firewall-net90d}],"name":Ethernet 1,"link":up,"id":1,"mode":1000BaseT-FD,"speed":1000,"rrd_id":1},{"duplex":half,"name":Ethernet 2,"link":down,"id":2,"mode":10BaseT-HD,"speed":10,"rrd_id":2},{"duplex":half,"name":Ethernet 3,"link":down,"id":3,"mode":10BaseT-HD,"speed":10,"rrd_id":3},{"duplex":half,"name":Ethernet 4,"link":down,"id":4,"mode":10BaseT-HD,"speed":10,"rrd_id":4},{"duplex":full,"name":NBAplug,"link":up,"id":5,"mode":1000BaseT-FD,"speed":1000,"rrd_id":nbaplug},{"duplex":auto,"mac_list":[{"mac":00:00:00:43:B3:73,"hostname":00:00:00:43:B3:73},{"mac":00:00:00:1A:66:60,"hostname":00:00:00:1A:66:60},{"mac":00:00:00:09:00:13,"hostname":00:00:00:09:00:13},{"mac":00:00:00:80:29:7C,"hostname":abcd-PLAYER},{"mac":00:00:00:09:00:12,"hostname":firewall-net101f-cluster},{"mac":00:00:00:A0:EF:82,"hostname":00:00:00:A0:EF:82}],"name":Sfp lan,"link":up,"id":9999,"mode":10000-FD,"speed":10000,"rrd_id":sfp_lan}]


And I need to write a jq dynamic filter (the depth of the json is not predictible) that produce the exact same output in every situations.
For the moment, I did approach the goal with the following filter, but I don't achieve to put the number of the part of each arrays in '[]' nor removing the first dot '.' and adding the '=' and the value for each keys (or json) value for each lines
Here is the jq filter :
jq -rc '[paths|map(("."+strings)//"[]")|join("")][]' 

With this filter, here is the output when processing the previous json :
.result
.result[]
.result[].duplex
.result[].mac_list
.result[].mac_list[]
.result[].mac_list[].mac
.result[].mac_list[].hostname
.result[].name
.result[].link
.result[].id
.result[].mode
.result[].speed
.result[].rrd_id
.result[]
.result[].duplex
.result[].name
.result[].link
.result[].id
.result[].mode
.result[].speed
.result[].rrd_id
.result[]
.result[].duplex
.result[].name
.result[].link
.result[].id
.result[].mode
.result[].speed
.result[].rrd_id
.result[]
.result[].duplex
.result[].name
.result[].link
.result[].id
.result[].mode
.result[].speed
.result[].rrd_id
.result[]
.result[].duplex
.result[].name
.result[].link
.result[].id
.result[].mode
.result[].speed
.result[].rrd_id
.result[]
.result[].duplex
.result[].mac_list
.result[].mac_list[]
.result[].mac_list[].mac
.result[].mac_list[].hostname
.result[].mac_list[]
.result[].mac_list[].mac
.result[].mac_list[].hostname
.result[].mac_list[]
.result[].mac_list[].mac
.result[].mac_list[].hostname
.result[].mac_list[]
.result[].mac_list[].mac
.result[].mac_list[].hostname
.result[].mac_list[]
.result[].mac_list[].mac
.result[].mac_list[].hostname
.result[].mac_list[]
.result[].mac_list[].mac
.result[].mac_list[].hostname
.result[].name
.result[].link
.result[].id
.result[].mode
.result[].speed
.result[].rrd_id

BASH parsing is not only slow, when using JSON file with more then 10^8 char, bash functions failed to parse (after hours of 100% CPU), and I read in JQ documentation that jq can handle json of more than 1 giga bytes size...
If a 'jq expert' could help here, it would be very appreciated
Kind regards
nbanba

You probably want something with --stream;  you might want to study the output of jq --stream -r '"\(.[0] | join(" ")) = \(.[1])"' to start.

(You'll need something a little more complicated than join(" ") to build the LHS of each "assignment".)

@chepner Thanks for help ! You're right, join(" ") dont seems to be the solution as the functions in @pmf answer don't use it and is working fine. But thanks again !

That was just a placeholder to observe what you get from consuming the stream :) I either forgot about or never knew about paths.

My answer uses add which in this case (when the input is an array of strings) is equivalent to join(""), i.e. the concatenation with an empty glue string, as by then all items have already been decorated with the necessary dots and brackets.

@pmf your true ! after testing, in the filter you provide in your answer, join(" ") approach add[1:] output at difference of : | sed -e 's/^\.r/r/g' -e 's/^\.s/s/g' -e '/^\ = {.*/d' (sorry for sed usage for removing the first dot and the last line, I'm not enough jq trained to rewrite it in jq language)

7min ! I cannot edit ... sorry ! The sed can be rewrite to | sed -e 's/^\.//g' -e '/^\ = {.*/d'

@nbanba Note that join(" ") (with a space) is not join("") (without it). And if you replace add with join(…), you still need [1:] to chop off the first character, i.e. you can replace add[1:] with join("")[1:]. Keep in mind that this unconditionally removes any first character (which is always a dot as long as the top-level item is an object). To only remove a single dot explicitly, use ltrimstr instead: add | ltrimstr(".") or join("") | ltrimstr(".").

@pmf Really thanks for all your explanations and help !

With paths you won't get the exact traversal order of your expected output. If this is not important, here's one approach using your attempt with paths:
paths as $p |
"\([$p[] | "." + strings // "[\(.)]"] | add[1:]) = \(getpath($p))"

success = true
result = [{"duplex":"full","mac_list":[{"mac":"00:00:00:2F:8E:AB","hostname":"firewall-net90d"}],"name":"Ethernet 1","link":"up","id":1,"mode":"1000BaseT-FD","speed":"1000","rrd_id":"1"},{"duplex":"half","name":"Ethernet 2","link":"down","id":2,"mode":"10BaseT-HD","speed":"10","rrd_id":"2"},{"duplex":"half","name":"Ethernet 3","link":"down","id":3,"mode":"10BaseT-HD","speed":"10","rrd_id":"3"},{"duplex":"half","name":"Ethernet 4","link":"down","id":4,"mode":"10BaseT-HD","speed":"10","rrd_id":"4"},{"duplex":"full","name":"NBAplug","link":"up","id":5,"mode":"1000BaseT-FD","speed":"1000","rrd_id":"nbaplug"},{"duplex":"auto","mac_list":[{"mac":"00:00:00:43:B3:73","hostname":"00:00:00:43:B3:73"},{"mac":"00:00:00:1A:66:60","hostname":"00:00:00:1A:66:60"},{"mac":"00:00:00:09:00:13","hostname":"00:00:00:09:00:13"},{"mac":"00:00:00:80:29:7C","hostname":"abcd-PLAYER"},{"mac":"00:00:00:09:00:12","hostname":"firewall-net101f-cluster"},{"mac":"00:00:00:A0:EF:82","hostname":"00:00:00:A0:EF:82"}],"name":"Sfp lan","link":"up","id":9999,"mode":"10000-FD","speed":"10000","rrd_id":"sfp_lan"}]
result[0] = {"duplex":"full","mac_list":[{"mac":"00:00:00:2F:8E:AB","hostname":"firewall-net90d"}],"name":"Ethernet 1","link":"up","id":1,"mode":"1000BaseT-FD","speed":"1000","rrd_id":"1"}
result[0].duplex = full
result[0].mac_list = [{"mac":"00:00:00:2F:8E:AB","hostname":"firewall-net90d"}]
result[0].mac_list[0] = {"mac":"00:00:00:2F:8E:AB","hostname":"firewall-net90d"}
result[0].mac_list[0].mac = 00:00:00:2F:8E:AB
result[0].mac_list[0].hostname = firewall-net90d
result[0].name = Ethernet 1
result[0].link = up
result[0].id = 1
result[0].mode = 1000BaseT-FD
result[0].speed = 1000
result[0].rrd_id = 1
result[1] = {"duplex":"half","name":"Ethernet 2","link":"down","id":2,"mode":"10BaseT-HD","speed":"10","rrd_id":"2"}
result[1].duplex = half
result[1].name = Ethernet 2
result[1].link = down
result[1].id = 2
result[1].mode = 10BaseT-HD
result[1].speed = 10
result[1].rrd_id = 2
result[2] = {"duplex":"half","name":"Ethernet 3","link":"down","id":3,"mode":"10BaseT-HD","speed":"10","rrd_id":"3"}
result[2].duplex = half
result[2].name = Ethernet 3
result[2].link = down
result[2].id = 3
result[2].mode = 10BaseT-HD
result[2].speed = 10
result[2].rrd_id = 3
result[3] = {"duplex":"half","name":"Ethernet 4","link":"down","id":4,"mode":"10BaseT-HD","speed":"10","rrd_id":"4"}
result[3].duplex = half
result[3].name = Ethernet 4
result[3].link = down
result[3].id = 4
result[3].mode = 10BaseT-HD
result[3].speed = 10
result[3].rrd_id = 4
result[4] = {"duplex":"full","name":"NBAplug","link":"up","id":5,"mode":"1000BaseT-FD","speed":"1000","rrd_id":"nbaplug"}
result[4].duplex = full
result[4].name = NBAplug
result[4].link = up
result[4].id = 5
result[4].mode = 1000BaseT-FD
result[4].speed = 1000
result[4].rrd_id = nbaplug
result[5] = {"duplex":"auto","mac_list":[{"mac":"00:00:00:43:B3:73","hostname":"00:00:00:43:B3:73"},{"mac":"00:00:00:1A:66:60","hostname":"00:00:00:1A:66:60"},{"mac":"00:00:00:09:00:13","hostname":"00:00:00:09:00:13"},{"mac":"00:00:00:80:29:7C","hostname":"abcd-PLAYER"},{"mac":"00:00:00:09:00:12","hostname":"firewall-net101f-cluster"},{"mac":"00:00:00:A0:EF:82","hostname":"00:00:00:A0:EF:82"}],"name":"Sfp lan","link":"up","id":9999,"mode":"10000-FD","speed":"10000","rrd_id":"sfp_lan"}
result[5].duplex = auto
result[5].mac_list = [{"mac":"00:00:00:43:B3:73","hostname":"00:00:00:43:B3:73"},{"mac":"00:00:00:1A:66:60","hostname":"00:00:00:1A:66:60"},{"mac":"00:00:00:09:00:13","hostname":"00:00:00:09:00:13"},{"mac":"00:00:00:80:29:7C","hostname":"abcd-PLAYER"},{"mac":"00:00:00:09:00:12","hostname":"firewall-net101f-cluster"},{"mac":"00:00:00:A0:EF:82","hostname":"00:00:00:A0:EF:82"}]
result[5].mac_list[0] = {"mac":"00:00:00:43:B3:73","hostname":"00:00:00:43:B3:73"}
result[5].mac_list[0].mac = 00:00:00:43:B3:73
result[5].mac_list[0].hostname = 00:00:00:43:B3:73
result[5].mac_list[1] = {"mac":"00:00:00:1A:66:60","hostname":"00:00:00:1A:66:60"}
result[5].mac_list[1].mac = 00:00:00:1A:66:60
result[5].mac_list[1].hostname = 00:00:00:1A:66:60
result[5].mac_list[2] = {"mac":"00:00:00:09:00:13","hostname":"00:00:00:09:00:13"}
result[5].mac_list[2].mac = 00:00:00:09:00:13
result[5].mac_list[2].hostname = 00:00:00:09:00:13
result[5].mac_list[3] = {"mac":"00:00:00:80:29:7C","hostname":"abcd-PLAYER"}
result[5].mac_list[3].mac = 00:00:00:80:29:7C
result[5].mac_list[3].hostname = abcd-PLAYER
result[5].mac_list[4] = {"mac":"00:00:00:09:00:12","hostname":"firewall-net101f-cluster"}
result[5].mac_list[4].mac = 00:00:00:09:00:12
result[5].mac_list[4].hostname = firewall-net101f-cluster
result[5].mac_list[5] = {"mac":"00:00:00:A0:EF:82","hostname":"00:00:00:A0:EF:82"}
result[5].mac_list[5].mac = 00:00:00:A0:EF:82
result[5].mac_list[5].hostname = 00:00:00:A0:EF:82
result[5].name = Sfp lan
result[5].link = up
result[5].id = 9999
result[5].mode = 10000-FD
result[5].speed = 10000
result[5].rrd_id = sfp_lan

Demo

To retain the order, write a postfix-recursive function that nests the way you want it. For example:
def f($p): f($p + (getpath($p) | iterables | keys_unsorted[] |[.])),
  "\([$p[] | "." + strings // "[\(.)]"] | add[1:] | values) = \(getpath($p))";
f([])

success = true
result[0].duplex = full
result[0].mac_list[0].mac = 00:00:00:2F:8E:AB
result[0].mac_list[0].hostname = firewall-net90d
result[0].mac_list[0] = {"mac":"00:00:00:2F:8E:AB","hostname":"firewall-net90d"}
result[0].mac_list = [{"mac":"00:00:00:2F:8E:AB","hostname":"firewall-net90d"}]
result[0].name = Ethernet 1
result[0].link = up
result[0].id = 1
result[0].mode = 1000BaseT-FD
result[0].speed = 1000
result[0].rrd_id = 1
result[0] = {"duplex":"full","mac_list":[{"mac":"00:00:00:2F:8E:AB","hostname":"firewall-net90d"}],"name":"Ethernet 1","link":"up","id":1,"mode":"1000BaseT-FD","speed":"1000","rrd_id":"1"}
result[1].duplex = half
result[1].name = Ethernet 2
result[1].link = down
result[1].id = 2
result[1].mode = 10BaseT-HD
result[1].speed = 10
result[1].rrd_id = 2
result[1] = {"duplex":"half","name":"Ethernet 2","link":"down","id":2,"mode":"10BaseT-HD","speed":"10","rrd_id":"2"}
result[2].duplex = half
result[2].name = Ethernet 3
result[2].link = down
result[2].id = 3
result[2].mode = 10BaseT-HD
result[2].speed = 10
result[2].rrd_id = 3
result[2] = {"duplex":"half","name":"Ethernet 3","link":"down","id":3,"mode":"10BaseT-HD","speed":"10","rrd_id":"3"}
result[3].duplex = half
result[3].name = Ethernet 4
result[3].link = down
result[3].id = 4
result[3].mode = 10BaseT-HD
result[3].speed = 10
result[3].rrd_id = 4
result[3] = {"duplex":"half","name":"Ethernet 4","link":"down","id":4,"mode":"10BaseT-HD","speed":"10","rrd_id":"4"}
result[4].duplex = full
result[4].name = NBAplug
result[4].link = up
result[4].id = 5
result[4].mode = 1000BaseT-FD
result[4].speed = 1000
result[4].rrd_id = nbaplug
result[4] = {"duplex":"full","name":"NBAplug","link":"up","id":5,"mode":"1000BaseT-FD","speed":"1000","rrd_id":"nbaplug"}
result[5].duplex = auto
result[5].mac_list[0].mac = 00:00:00:43:B3:73
result[5].mac_list[0].hostname = 00:00:00:43:B3:73
result[5].mac_list[0] = {"mac":"00:00:00:43:B3:73","hostname":"00:00:00:43:B3:73"}
result[5].mac_list[1].mac = 00:00:00:1A:66:60
result[5].mac_list[1].hostname = 00:00:00:1A:66:60
result[5].mac_list[1] = {"mac":"00:00:00:1A:66:60","hostname":"00:00:00:1A:66:60"}
result[5].mac_list[2].mac = 00:00:00:09:00:13
result[5].mac_list[2].hostname = 00:00:00:09:00:13
result[5].mac_list[2] = {"mac":"00:00:00:09:00:13","hostname":"00:00:00:09:00:13"}
result[5].mac_list[3].mac = 00:00:00:80:29:7C
result[5].mac_list[3].hostname = abcd-PLAYER
result[5].mac_list[3] = {"mac":"00:00:00:80:29:7C","hostname":"abcd-PLAYER"}
result[5].mac_list[4].mac = 00:00:00:09:00:12
result[5].mac_list[4].hostname = firewall-net101f-cluster
result[5].mac_list[4] = {"mac":"00:00:00:09:00:12","hostname":"firewall-net101f-cluster"}
result[5].mac_list[5].mac = 00:00:00:A0:EF:82
result[5].mac_list[5].hostname = 00:00:00:A0:EF:82
result[5].mac_list[5] = {"mac":"00:00:00:A0:EF:82","hostname":"00:00:00:A0:EF:82"}
result[5].mac_list = [{"mac":"00:00:00:43:B3:73","hostname":"00:00:00:43:B3:73"},{"mac":"00:00:00:1A:66:60","hostname":"00:00:00:1A:66:60"},{"mac":"00:00:00:09:00:13","hostname":"00:00:00:09:00:13"},{"mac":"00:00:00:80:29:7C","hostname":"abcd-PLAYER"},{"mac":"00:00:00:09:00:12","hostname":"firewall-net101f-cluster"},{"mac":"00:00:00:A0:EF:82","hostname":"00:00:00:A0:EF:82"}]
result[5].name = Sfp lan
result[5].link = up
result[5].id = 9999
result[5].mode = 10000-FD
result[5].speed = 10000
result[5].rrd_id = sfp_lan
result[5] = {"duplex":"auto","mac_list":[{"mac":"00:00:00:43:B3:73","hostname":"00:00:00:43:B3:73"},{"mac":"00:00:00:1A:66:60","hostname":"00:00:00:1A:66:60"},{"mac":"00:00:00:09:00:13","hostname":"00:00:00:09:00:13"},{"mac":"00:00:00:80:29:7C","hostname":"abcd-PLAYER"},{"mac":"00:00:00:09:00:12","hostname":"firewall-net101f-cluster"},{"mac":"00:00:00:A0:EF:82","hostname":"00:00:00:A0:EF:82"}],"name":"Sfp lan","link":"up","id":9999,"mode":"10000-FD","speed":"10000","rrd_id":"sfp_lan"}
result = [{"duplex":"full","mac_list":[{"mac":"00:00:00:2F:8E:AB","hostname":"firewall-net90d"}],"name":"Ethernet 1","link":"up","id":1,"mode":"1000BaseT-FD","speed":"1000","rrd_id":"1"},{"duplex":"half","name":"Ethernet 2","link":"down","id":2,"mode":"10BaseT-HD","speed":"10","rrd_id":"2"},{"duplex":"half","name":"Ethernet 3","link":"down","id":3,"mode":"10BaseT-HD","speed":"10","rrd_id":"3"},{"duplex":"half","name":"Ethernet 4","link":"down","id":4,"mode":"10BaseT-HD","speed":"10","rrd_id":"4"},{"duplex":"full","name":"NBAplug","link":"up","id":5,"mode":"1000BaseT-FD","speed":"1000","rrd_id":"nbaplug"},{"duplex":"auto","mac_list":[{"mac":"00:00:00:43:B3:73","hostname":"00:00:00:43:B3:73"},{"mac":"00:00:00:1A:66:60","hostname":"00:00:00:1A:66:60"},{"mac":"00:00:00:09:00:13","hostname":"00:00:00:09:00:13"},{"mac":"00:00:00:80:29:7C","hostname":"abcd-PLAYER"},{"mac":"00:00:00:09:00:12","hostname":"firewall-net101f-cluster"},{"mac":"00:00:00:A0:EF:82","hostname":"00:00:00:A0:EF:82"}],"name":"Sfp lan","link":"up","id":9999,"mode":"10000-FD","speed":"10000","rrd_id":"sfp_lan"}]

Demo

Really thanks a lot ! it seems to be nearly perfect, I will try it now !
At the first reading I did notice some very small differences coming from bash quote interpretation on the bash functions (not sure it will have an impact), for example the bash function output (... result[5].mac_list[0] = {"mac":00:00:00:43:B3:73,"hostname":00:00:00:43:B3:73} where jq output it result[5].mac_list[0] = {"mac":"00:00:00:43:B3:73","hostname":"00:00:00:43:B3:73"}), but as previously said, not sure it have a negative impact. I let you know ... and thanks gain !

@nbanba The lines affected are the ones where the JSON value is not a scalar (numbers, strings, etc.) but an iterable (arrays or objects). In your bash output, these lines are almost JSON-encoded. They only lack the enclosing double quotes for strings (as required by JSON) when they appear as object values (for the keys they're present), see {"mac":00:00:00:43:B3:73, …} vs {"mac":"00:00:00:43:B3:73", …}. While it is possible to reproduce this invalid JSON encoding, it'd be quite tedious to rewrite a near-JSON encoder as jq is already optimized to output valid JSON.

It seems to be perfect, really thanks ! (after "small" testing, it seems to have NO impact on the rest of the code)
have a function (ls_fs) which parse an 222340 char json send by an API and running it with 'time' using the provided jq filter show a huge difference : with jq :    3,089s and with pure bash parsing : 59,623s
